# Update Image after Info Marker Window is shown

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I am new to ios and I'm not sure how I could update a google maps custom marker info window image after my http post request is complete.

My current custom marker info window xib looks like this

[Custom Marker Info Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDhg8.png)

In my delegate method 
mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker) I made an Alamofire.request which fetches my image for me. I want the user to be able to immediately to see the info window without waiting for the image to be complete. The request is as follows

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, appDelegate.host + "/get-img", parameters: params as? [String : AnyObject], encoding: .JSON , headers: headers)
    .response{ (request, response, data, error) in
        if let img = data {
            infoWindow.img.image = UIImage(data: img)
        }
    }
```

however the image in the info window does not update at all. I understand that google maps api stated that the view may not update after returning the view in the delegate method but are there any other workarounds?

I have also considered requesting for all images relating to all markers on the map before the map view is loaded but that may just be too expensive.

Answer (score 3):

I solved a similar problem by setting:

```
marker.tracksInfoWindowChanges = true
```

in the mapView markerInfoWindow method (before requesting the image) and then after image is loaded (i.e. in the "response" handler), I set the image in the infoWindow and then set the flag back, so it doesn't consume resources ([see tracksInfoWindowChanges docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/marker#set_an_info_window_to_refresh_automatically)):

```
marker.tracksInfoWindowChanges = false
```